# Entity Framework Cannot Get Entity and Gives "Object's Key Does Not Match.." Error

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-5

I am stucked in my project and would really appreciate any help. I am using **EF 5 Code-First** approach.

Here is my base entity:

```
...
public virtual Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        protected set { }

    }

public virtual bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
...
```

And my entity:

```
...
public string CountryName { get; set; }
public string CountryCode { get; set; }
public Coordinate CountryCoordinate { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<City> Cities
{
    get
    {
        if (_cities == null)
        {
            _cities = new HashSet<City>();
        }

        return _cities;
    }
    private set
    {
        _cities = new HashSet<City>(value);
    }
}
...
```

And it's configuration:

```
public CountryEntityConfiguration()
{
this.HasKey(c => c.Id);

this.Property(c => c.CountryName)
    .HasMaxLength(64)
    .IsRequired();

this.Property(c => c.CountryCode)
    .HasMaxLength(4)
    .IsRequired();

this.HasMany(c => c.Cities)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(ci => ci.CountryId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
}
```

There are other stuff for repository, complex type for coordinate value object and cities etc.

Now when I try to call GetEntity(Guid Id) over CountryRepository I get an error saying:

> The value of a property that is part of an object's key does not match
>   the corresponding property value stored in the ObjectContext.  This
>   can occur if properties that are part of the key return inconsistent
>   or incorrect values or if DetectChanges is not called after changes
>   are made to a property that is part of the key.

I have searched a lot but every answer was about combined PK's, empty columns etc. While testin I seed the DB and can see that rows and columns are ok.

So what did I have done completely wrong, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok finally I could figure it out. It was the entity base with empty setter causing the problem. Somehow (may be after hours of work) I skipped the setter function for the Id. So adding _id = value to the Id property solved the problem. Phew..!

```
public virtual Guid Id
{
    get { return _id; }
    protected set { _id = value }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exception message but very different reason.
I had a string Id column that was contaminated with trailing spaces. Try to see if your values in column Id contains whitespace.

Comment: Please consider adding a code snippet to illustrate how your answer answers the OP's question